# Как правильно присвоить указатель на функцию?

Tags: c++

Есть класс, который содержит метод doX и указатель на функцию pDoX.

```
class X
{
public:
    void (*pDoX)();
    void doX();

    X()
    {
        pDoX = doX;
    }
};
```

Если компилировать код, выводится ошибка:

> `x.c: In constructor ‘X::X()’:`
> `x.c:9: error: argument of type ‘void (X::)()’ does not match ‘void (*)()’`

Как осуществить присвоение правильно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Компилятор должен знать, какому объекту "посылать мессидж" при обращении к функции, спрятанной за указателем, поэтому тип переменной должен быть соответствующий

```
class X
{
public:
    void (X::*pDoX)();
    void doX();

    X()
    {
        pDoX = &X::doX;
    }
};
```

Только вызывать придётся, указывая конкретный объект:

```
int main()
{
    X x;
    (x.*(x.pDoX))();
    return 0;
}
```

или так:

```
int main()
{
    X *px = new X();
    (px->*(px->pDoX))();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: а в какого рода задачах это требуется. не подскажете?

Comment: <pre>void (*do_smth)(void);
void Win9x_do_smth(void);
void Win2k_do_smth(void);
void WinXP_do_smth(void);

//где-то в код
ver = CheckForWindowsVersion();
if (ver = Win9x) do_smth = Win9x_do_smth;
else if (ver = Win2k) do_smth = Win2k_do_smth;
else if (ver = WinXP) do_smth = WinXP_do_smth;

// где-то дальше в коде
do_smth(); // для ХР вызывается по факту void WinXP_do_smth(void)</pre>

Comment: Можно использовать массив указателей на функции и выбирать нужный. Стоит только приложить фантазию. Еще указатели на функции нужны при работе с динамическими библиотеками. Так можно реализовать систему плагинов.
В вышеуказанном примере указатель нужен для выбора конкретной функции из множества, которая будет вызываться при работе программы под конкретной ОС.