# Хранение в переменной указателя на функцию

Tags: c++, классы, функции, указатели

Пытаюсь научить класс сохранять функции. Например, при написании менеджера текстур, указать функцию, которая будет загружать эти текстуры; при этом пользователь может выбрать любую, какую захочет, а менеджер будет её использовать.

Нашёл [подобный  вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/8692/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E), на основе найденной информации набросал пример. То, что мне нужно, не получается - я пометил эти места комментариями с вопросительным знаком.

Вот пример:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class TEST
{
public:
//private:


    int (TEST::*UKAZ_ARG)(int a, int b);  //Переменная для хранения выбранной функции

    int A_SUM(int a, int b)             //Возможная функция 1
    {
        return a+b;
    }

    int A_MNO(int a, int b)             //Возможная функция 2
    {
        return a*b;
    }

public:

    TEST() //Конструктор 
    {
        UKAZ_ARG = &TEST::A_MNO; //Функция по умолчанию
    }


    void ARG_REGIST( int  (*func)(int,int)  )
    {
       // UKAZ_ARG = *func;  //Не работает. Почему ?
    }

    int ROZRAH(int a,int b) //Функция, которая вызывает указатель на функцию (для красивого вызова)
    {
        //return TEST::((*UKAZ_ARG)(a,b));  //Не работает. Почему ?
    }

};



    int A_MNO_DIL(int a, int b)             //Возможная функция 3
    {
        return (a*b)/2;
    }




int main()
{
    TEST ob1;

    ob1.ARG_REGIST(A_MNO_DIL); //Не функционирует
    //cout<<ob1.UKAZ_ARG(5,5);
    cout<<(ob1.*(ob1.UKAZ_ARG))(5,10); //Не красиво и неудобно.   Пытаюсь упаковать в `ROZRAH`, но в классе конструкция не работает

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А вот эта функция, которую вы пытаетесь установить должна ли иметь доступ к свойствам экземпляра данного класса ? Если да - то объявлена она правильно, как член класса, при этом помимо двух int она получает еще this, но тогда вы не можете присвоить ей функцию из вне этого класса, так как никакого this у нее нет и быть не может. Если же доступ не нужен, то тогда не надо объявлять ее как член класса и тогда вы сможете использовать как параметры любые внешние функции или же статические члены класса (в которых так же нет this)

Comment: Мне нужно доступ и изнутри и из вне, доступ из вне. Присвоение функции из вне более приоритетное.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В первом вопросе у вас `UKAZ_ARG` - указатель на функцию-член, а вы пытаетесь передать ему свободную функцию. Это совсем разные виды функций. Ведь фактически какая-нибудь `A_MNO` получает *три* аргумента - два `int`, и еще один - объект `TEST`, для которого вызывается. А `A_MNO_DIL` - только два `int`'а. Вот во избежание неверного вызова такое присваивание и невозможно...

Во втором - у вас есть указатель на функцию-член, а вы вызываете ее фактически как статическую, не указывая нужный объект, для которого ее нужно вызвать (см. выше о *третьем* аргументе вызова). Чтобы заработало, пишите

```
return (this->*UKAZ_ARG)(a,b);
```

Comment: С вторым всё получилось. А первое сделать как. Видел в библиотеке glut регистрацию функции обработки клавиатуры  мышки и т.д.  библиотека как то сохраняет функцию которою я ей передаю  и вызывает как событие.

Comment: Смотрите - у вас ведь в ваших функциях `A_MNO` да `A_SUM` нигде не используется сам объект класса. Ну так сделайте их `static`, и объявите `int (*UKAZ_ARG)(int a, int b);`. Кстати, и его тоже можно сделать статическим.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, всё заработало

Answer (score 0):

Всьо заработало. Вот результат

```
#include<iostream>
    using namespace std;

    class TEST
    {
    public:
    //private:


        int (*UKAZ_ARG)(int a, int b);  //Переменная для хранения выбраной функцыи

        static int A_SUM(int a, int b)              //Возможная фушкция 1
        {
            return a+b;
        }

        static int A_MNO(int a, int b)              //Возможная фушкция 2
        {
            return a*b;
        }

    public:

        TEST() //Конструктор 
        {
            UKAZ_ARG = &TEST::A_MNO; //Функия по умолчанию
        }


        void ARG_REGIST(static int  (*func)(int a,int b)  )
        {
           // UKAZ_ARG = *func;  //Не работает Почему ?
            UKAZ_ARG = *func;
        }

        int ROZRAH(int a,int b) //Функция которая вызивает указать функцыю (Для красивого вызова)
        {
            //return TEST::((*UKAZ_ARG)(a,b)); //Не работает почему ?
            return (this->UKAZ_ARG)(a,b);
        }

    };



        int A_MNO_DIL(int a, int b)             //Возможная фушкция 3
        {
            return (a*b)/2;
        }




    int main()
    {
        TEST ob1;

        ob1.ARG_REGIST(A_MNO_DIL); //не функционирует
        //cout<<ob1.UKAZ_ARG(5,5);
        cout<<ob1.ROZRAH(5,10); //Не красивр и не удобно   пытаюсь упаковать в ROZRAH но в классе конструкция не работает

        cin.get();
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Более унивирсально использовать std::function

```
class TEST
{
    std::function<int(int, int)> UKAZ_ARG;
public:
    TEST() 
    {
        UKAZ_ARG = [this](int a, int b) { A_MNO(a, b); } // <- тут создали лямбда функцию для вызова A_MNO
    }

    void ARG_REGIST(cons std::function<int(int, int)>& func)
    {
        UKAZ_ARG = func;
    }

    int ROZRAH(int a,int b) 
    {
        return UKAZ_ARG(a, b);
    }
}
void main() 
{
    TEST test;
    std::cout << test.ROZRAH(1, 2); // print "2" -> A_MNO(1, 2) == 2

    test.ARG_REGIST([&test](int a, int b) { return test.A_SUM(1,2); });
    std::cout << test.ROZRAH(1, 2); // print "3"

    test.ARG_REGIST([](int a, int b) { return a + b + 1; });
    std::cout << test.ROZRAH(1, 2); // print "4" -> a=1 + b=2 + 1 == 4
}
```

Comment: Тогда уж хотя бы     `TEST() 
    {
        UKAZ_ARG = [this](int a, int b) { return this->A_MNO(a, b); }; // <- тут создали лямбда функцию для вызова A_MNO
    }`

Comment: Пример не работает (куча ошибок)

Comment: @Harry, это вкусовщина писать или нет this, я за то чтоб не писать.

Comment: @ffk Ну... в общем-то да... Но как по мне - так куда понятнее.